# setting conditional attributes for API connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A method needs to instantiate a session with various attributes, some of which are optional

```
session = Checkout::Session.create({
            locale: I18n.locale,
            reference_id: id,
            customer_email: @user_mail,
            [...]
          })
```

The last shown attribute, `customer_email`, is  optional but it should not be generated if the value does not exist.

```
customer_email: @user_mail unless !@user_email,
```

logically hits a syntax error because an additional param (the comma) is being produced

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end
```

and thus the API expects another attribute.

```
(customer_email: @user_mail, unless !@user_email)
```

also fails as there is confusion over the parenthesis

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting then or ';' or '\n'
```

How should this syntax be cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the options hash into a variable and manipulate it before sending it to the `Checkout::Session.create`.

Something like this:

```
 options = {
   locale: I18n.locale,
   reference_id: id
 }
 options[:customer_email] = @user_mail if @user_email
 session = Checkout::Session.create(options)
```